# Getting data out of structure not working

Tags: powershell, where-clause

I'm trying to get the data out of the data structure, and I can see it's in there, but the variable the info is assigned to is null.

Let me know if you need more info for the method that assigns $SizeBasedVideoStringDevice, but it looks like this:

```
$SizeBasedVideoStringDevice:
[Object[7]]:
[0]:@{Key=LOAD_MEDIA;VALUE=SYSTEM.OBJECT[]}
[1]:@{KEY=LOAD_MEDIAB;VALUE=}
[2]:@{KEY=LOAD_MEDIAC;VALUE=}
[3]:@{KEY=LOAD_MEDIAD;VALUE=SYSTEM.OBJECT[]}
...
```

So some of them have a Value, which is fine.

When I look closer at that first value, it looks like this:

```
Value: [Object[5]]
[0]: "LoadDialog.MediaA"
[1]: "LoadDialog.MediaB"
[2]: "LoadDialog.MediaC"
...
```

I have the following code, and for some reason it's not finding that first one. Once I get the data out, I will loop thru and process each Value.

```
$tmp = "LOAD_MEDIA" #this will match first in data structure
$sizeBasedVideoString = $SizeBasedVideoStringDevice.where{$_Key -eq $tmp}.Value ###this is null
if($null -ne $sizeBasedVideoString) 
{
   $resultDPS_sized = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[string]
   foreach($vid in $sizeBasedVideoString)
   { 
       #get vid location
       $temp = ProcessDPSMDB -mdbLookupString $vid -mdbFilePath $dpsMdbPathFull
       $resultDPS_sized.Add($temp)
   }
}
```

This is using PowerShell 5.1 and VSCode.

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you want, are you looking to get all the `Values` of the objects in `$SizeBasedVideoStringDevice` ?

Comment: Yea, when the key matches, I need to get the Value out. Then I'll get each one out of Value and put it in a list. In a short while, I'll put that info in my spreadsheet.

Comment: `$SizeBasedVideoStringDevice |Where Key -eq 'keyValue' |Select -Expand Value` should do

Comment: You have a typo as far as I can see that should be the only problem... `$_Key` should be `$_.Key`

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon - Thank you! That was it!! It was a typo.  If you want to post the solution I'll accept it.  :)

Comment: No worries Michele, you can self-answer if you want to :)